# Bootstrap Menu Vertical Dividing

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to separate sub menu items vertically using bootstrap. I have done the separation horizontally. But I would like to separate them vertically. As I am new to bootstrap can anyone help me on this?

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Bank Accounts<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li> 
  </ul>
</li>
```

What I need is to display the first 3 elements (with header) in one column and the last two elements (with header) in another column separated by a line.

Comment: Please state clearly what CSS you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's documentation is plentiful: http://getbootstrap.com/components/

If you spent more time studying the tool that you're using, this question would not be necessary.

Here's a simple example, but there are several ways to do this: http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/yHCSL8drbO

I've trimmed a lot of the Bootstrap fat from the markup.

```css
ul.t {
  padding: 0 2px;
}

ul.t li {
  padding: 0 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="pull-left">
      <ul class="list-unstyled t">
        <li><a href="#">Bootply</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One itmus ac facilin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Secondp t eros</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="pull-right">
      <ul class="list-unstyled t">
        <li><a href="#">Bootply</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One itmus ac facilin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Secondp t eros</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li><li>
    </li></ul>
</div>

<!-- Resources... -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Hmm that's not really an answer - Either ignore it or explain in some detail what should be done

Comment: Okay, I've added a small example, but you should know that by hand feeding help vampires code like this reinforces their inability to devise solutions for themselves. Questions that show low effort in their attempts to solve the problem should be rewarded with simple answers. Learning to read documentation and seek out the useful information is one of the greatest things you can teach someone.